# status: 405, ok: false, statusText: "Method Not Allowed"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, kendo-ui

- I am new to angular 2 and js.
- when I use the service url I am getting an error.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing relevant code and error below.
- providing whole code in the fiddle since I could not paste it here

https://jsfiddle.net/mncb1bt9/

whole.isports.com/swimmings/v1/document?timestamp=1501104688758:1 GET http://whole.isports.com/swimmings/v1/document?timestamp=1501104688758 405 (Method Not Allowed)
    VM3789:27 An error occurred Response {_body: "{"timestamp":1501104694800,"status":405,"error":"M… not supported","path":"/swimmings/v1/document"}", status: 405, ok: false, statusText: "Method Not Allowed", headers: Headers…}

```or-tag-here
    laughing(): void{
        console.log("documentsClicked");

        //let box;
        let title;
        let excelFileName;
        let runningNo;
        let url;
        let netNo;

        let that = this;
        title="View Airings";
        excelFileName="ViewAiringsExport";

        //url = "runningsaggregator/v1/running/airings/123/456";
        url = "swimmings/v1/document";

        let box = [
                        { field:'contextRow',title:" ", width: 25, locked: true },
                        { field:"Fox",  filterable:that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("eq","Fox"),headerAttributes: {class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled"}, title: "File Name", width: 200, editable: false,
                            template: function Fox(options){
                                return that.gridTemplate(options,"Fox",false);
                            }
                        },                          
                        { field: "Bat", filterable:that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains","Bat"),headerAttributes: {class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled"},  title: "Added By", width: 200, editable: false,
                            template: function Bat(options){
                                return that.gridTemplate(options,"Bat",false);
                            }
                        },
                        { field: "Lion", filterable:that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains","Lion"),headerAttributes: {class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled"},  title: "Added Date", width: 200, editable: false,
                            template: function Lion(options){
                                return that.gridTemplate(options,"Lion",false);
                            }
                        },
                        { field: "Ant", filterable:that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains","Ant"),headerAttributes: {class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled"},  title: "Program/Show Name", width: 200, editable: false,
                            template: function Ant(options){
                                return that.gridTemplate(options,"Ant",false);
                            }
                        },
                        { field: "Tiger", filterable:that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains","Tiger"),headerAttributes: {class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled"},  title: "Episode Name", width: 200, editable: false,
                            template: function Tiger(options){
                                return that.gridTemplate(options,"Tiger",false);
                            }
                        },
                        { field: "Monkey", filterable:that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains","Monkey"),headerAttributes: {class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled"},  title: "Format", width: 200, editable: false,
                            template: function Monkey(options){
                                return that.gridTemplate(options,"Monkey",false);
                            }
                        },
                        { field: "Zoo", filterable:that.gridkendo.getAutoFilterName("contains","Zoo"),headerAttributes: {class: "multiCheckboxFilterEnabled"},  title: "Program Type", width: 200, editable: false,
                            template: function Zoo(options){
                                return that.gridTemplate(options,"Zoo",false);
                            }
                        }
        ];
        let yellow={"url":url,"box":box,"title":title,"excelFileName":excelFileName};
        this.swimmingDocuments.openPopup(yellow);

        console.log("yellow--->" + yellow);

    }
```

Comment: Sounds like they want something other than a GET request

Comment: @epascarello so how to fix it ?? :(

Comment: Sounds like somewhere you should be making a POST request. I do not see where you are making the http call in the code.

Comment: @epascarello hello I pasted whole code in fiddle...can you help me https://jsfiddle.net/mncb1bt9/

Comment: possibly line 175 - there's a `'get'` on that line

Comment: @JaromandaX but inside the method documentsClicked I don't see any get...I started getting error after including this method